# Equivalent of thread.interrupt_main() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, keyboardinterrupt

In Python 2 there is a function `thread.interrupt_main()`, which raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the main thread when called from a subthread.

This is also available through `_thread.interrupt_main()` in Python 3, but it's a low-level "support module", mostly for use within other standard modules.

What is the modern way of doing this in Python 3, presumably through the `threading` module, if there is one?

Answer (score 9):

Well raising an exception manually is kinda low-level, so if you think you have to do that just use `_thread.interrupt_main()` since that's the equivalent you asked for (`threading` module itself doesn't provide this).

It could be that there is a more elegant way to achieve your ultimate goal, though. Maybe setting and checking a flag would be already enough or using a `threading.Event` like @RFmyD already suggested, or using message passing over a `queue.Queue`. It depends on your specific setup.

Comment: thanks for the `_thread` hint. Not sure about OP but in my case I run a thread to monitor whether a process should run and then process runs in main thread (regardless of the monitor implementation), so I couldn't find any other way than using interrupt_main to kill main process

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way for a thread to stop execution of the whole program, this is how I did it with a `threading.Event`:

```
def start():
    """
    This runs in the main thread and starts a sub thread
    """
    
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    check_stop_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=check_stop_signal, args=(stop_event), daemon=True
    )
    check_stop_thread.start()
    # If check_stop_thread sets the check_stop_signal, sys.exit() is executed here in the main thread.
    # Since the sub thread is a daemon, it will be terminated as well.
    stop_event.wait()
    logging.debug("Threading stop event set, calling sys.exit()...")
    sys.exit()




def check_stop_signal(stop_event):
    """
    Checks continuously (every 0.1 s) if a "stop" flag has been set in the database.
    Needs to run in its own thread.
    """
    while True:
        if io.check_stop():
            logger.info("Program was aborted by user.")
            logging.debug("Setting threading stop event...")
            stop_event.set()
            break
        sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into the threading.Event module.

Comment: Hi @RFmyD. Please note that this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post - From Review

Comment: @toti08 I think it's a valid answer, it's not a comment. A comment serves to improve the question, and in this case what is pointed out is a possible solution.